# Asking user confirmation before redirect to a clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long kind wizard form, like a survey in my site. I want to write a jQuery Function so that when the user click accidentally any link on the page ( except preview and next buttons of the wizard ), it is asked first: are you sure you want to proceed? then it is redirected to the link he clicked, if he click cancel, nothing happens..

So far What i have done is to each link of the page except (next & previw) i have added a class `link_ridirect` so i can grab  all the anchor links. and stop redirecting.

jQuery function is as follow!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- HERE IS THE SEARCH FILTER -->
 //<![CDATA[
    var GLOBAL_NAMESPACE = {};
    $(document).ready(function(){
      GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed = true;
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.link_redirect').bind('click',function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed){
              var res = confirm('you have unsaved changes. Do you want to continue?');
              if(res){
                  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
              }else{
                  console.log('stay on same page...');
              }
          }
      });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

So what i want to do is how can i declare a Global variable to keep track of all field state. So if a field changes,  to make it true and call the prevent function.

Comment: Are all links just anchors like `<a href="url">link</a>` ?

Comment: @nl-x yes they are! or at least those that im interested in to prevent from redirecting automaticlly they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have code to interrupt default A-tag clicks already, so the crux of this is to detect when a field has changed such that you want to ask if they want to save before navigating away ?

Here's a JSFiddle  [Detect Field Changes](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5q6/4/) :

It adds an onchange event to all editable fields whcih sets the global stae to true if something changed.

If the user enters a field then exits without changing, no change is detected.

```
function setup() {
  // bind the change event to all editable fields. Runs on load(or doc ready)
  $("input,select").bind("change",function(e) {
      GLOBAL_NAMESPACE.value_changed = true;
  });  
};
```

Comment: thanx, that's exacly what i was looking for ;)

Answer (score 3):

How about doing this:

```
 $('a').click(function(){return confirm("are you sure?");});
```

Place it at the bottom of your html, or in the onload of your page, or in the document ready as you suggested in your OP.

**edit**
If you only want to do this if your variable `changesDetected` is `true`, then do it like this:

```
 $('a').click(function(){return !changesDetected || confirm("are you sure?");});
```

Comment: Yes the function i wrote works perfect. But i was wondering if i could have just a variable to check all the fields of the form if there are any changes in the form. If there is then stop the user from redirecting

Answer (score 2):

you need to use *beforeunload* event. This event handled when you go out from page.

```
$(this).on("beforeunload", function () {
                return 'are you sure';
            });
```

if you need, that event called not for preview button and next, you can unbind this event handler.

```
    $('#myPreviewButtonId').click(function()
{
          console.log('preview clicked');
          $(this).unbind("beforeunload");
});
```

Comment: beforeunload displayed standart browser dialog with 'Leave this page', 'Stay on this page' buttons. So, when i return string, this string will be in this message dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkFileType = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            allowedExtensions: [],
            success: function() {},
            error: function() {}
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {

            $(this).on('change', function() {
                var value = $(this).val(),
                    file = value.toLowerCase(),
                    extension = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                if ($.inArray(extension, options.allowedExtensions) == -1) {
                    options.error();
                    $(this).focus();
                } else {
                    options.success();

                }

            });

        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('#image').checkFileType({
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg'],
        success: function() {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label for="image">Upload image (JPEG only)</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must prevent the default action on a if result of confirm function is false

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".deleteJob").on("click", function (e) {
    if (!confirm("Are you Sure want to delete!")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

});